# How to reference a React Component class from outside the render function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to reference a React Component in an object that I will later use for rendering in another component. i.e.,

```
class FruitAnimation extends Component {
    render() {
        return <div>{this.props.name}</div>
    }
}

const GROCERIES = [
    {
        name: 'banana',
        animation: FruitAnimation,
        ...
    },
    ...
]

class App extends Component {
    state = {
        current: 'banana'
    }

    getGrocery = name => _.find(GROCERIES, grocery => grocery.name === name);

    render() {
        const { name, animation: Animation } = this.getGrocery(this.state.current);

        return <Animation name={name} />
    }
}
```

However, I'm receiving this error when rendering:

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: null.

Check the render method of `App`.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Custom React components (components that are not regular html tags like `h1` or `p`) must be capitalized in order to be valid JSX. So `animation` would need to be `Animation`:

```
const GROCERIES = [
    {
        name: 'banana',
        Animation: FruitAnimation,
        ...
    },
    ...
]

// ...

render() {
    const { name, Animation } = this.getGrocery(this.state.current);
    return <Animation name={name} />
}
```

More here: https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized

Comment: I've updated my post. Still encountering the same error after reassigning it to a const with uppercase `Animation` :/

Comment: I'd suggest logging out `animation` in your render method then, and/or debugging that your `find` method is working. Might be that something is up with how you're pulling out the item in your grocery array. Try hardcoding getGrocery to always return the first item and see if that works first?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to iterate an array of objects which will return a number of items.
As per react from a functional component or class component it should return a single item.

```
class App extends Component {
    state = {
        current: 'banana'
    }

    getGrocery = name => _.find(GROCERIES, grocery => grocery.name === name);

    render() {

        return (
        <React.Fragment>
          this.getGrocery(this.state.current).map((fruit) => (
              <animation name={fruit.name} />
          ))

        </React.Fragment>
        );

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try with this.

```
const FruitAnimation = (name) => (
    <div>{name}</div>
);


const GROCERIES = [
    {
        name: 'banana',
        animation: FruitAnimation,
        ...
    },
    ...
]

class App extends Component {
    state = {
        current: 'banana'
    }

    getGrocery = name => _.find(GROCERIES, grocery => grocery.name === name);

    render() {
        const { name, animation: Animation } = this.getGrocery(this.state.current);

        return <Animation name={name} />
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should return a component or string inside render function try this...

```
class App extends Component {
        render() {
            return (
            <div>
              {
                GROCERIES.map((key, value) => {
                  return(<animation name={value.name}/>)
                })
              }
            </div>
            )
        }
    }
```

Comment: <animation /> will be treated as html by jsx.